# How to make hibernate enhancement plugin ignore some classes?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I use *hibernate-enhancement-plugin* in my project to implement lazy loading of some entities. But also I have a class AuditEntity that inherits from class *DefaultTrackingModifiedEntitiesRevisionEntity* from hibernate-envers library.

Plugin tries to enhance properties of AuditEnity which was inherited from the parent, but crashes with NPE, because parent was not enhanced.

Can i ignore this class somehow from enhancement?

AuditEntity looks like:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Revisions")
@RevisionEntity(RevisionListenerImpl.class)
public class AuditEntity extends DefaultTrackingModifiedEntitiesRevisionEntity {

    @Column(name="user_id")
    private String userId;

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
}
```

It crashes with error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.hibernate.envers.DefaultTrackingModifiedEntitiesRevisionEntity.$$_hibernate_write_timestamp(J)V
>     at
>   com.netcracker.mano.om.model.entities.AuditEntity.$$_hibernate_write_timestamp(AuditEntity.java)
>   ~[classes/:na]    ... 48 common frames omitted

*timestamp is property inherited by parent

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect that is likely a bug.  Could you open a bug report at https://hibernate.atlassian.net and provide a test case so that I can look into it for you?

That said, I would try changing `AuditEntity` to include all the parent class behavior directly, so essentially your implementation would look like the following and see if that enhances fine for now.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Revisions")
@RevisionEntity(RevisionListenerImpl.class)
public class AuditEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @RevisionNumber
  private int id;

  @RevisionTimestamp
  private long timestamp;

  @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinTable(name = "REVCHANGES", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "REV"))
  @Column(name = "ENTITYNAME")
  @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
  @ModifiedEntityNames
  private Set<String> modifiedEntityNames = new HashSet<>();

  @Column(name = "user_id")
  private String userId;

  // Getters, Setters, hashCode/equals implementations
  // Be sure to copy the hashCode/equals behavior from the two super types 
  //   - DefaultRevisionEntity
  //   - DefaultTrackingModifiedEntitiesRevisionEntity
}
```

On a unrelated note, I would also probably suggest a slight change in naming of this class too.  Envers has a class with the exact name that exposes a plethora of query predicate helpers that you'll use when writing a custom envers query.  In the event you write custom  queries that return your revision-entity class above, you'll need to fully qualify one of the objects which hinders readability imho.